# How to get actual value from php array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This `"<?php echo $array1["+i+"]; ?>"` is code that should get and return some coordinate from array at string from actual index. I would like to return actual coordinate, therefore I have there i(int) but some in this part is wrong. But if I rewrite to fixed index like this:  `"<?php echo $array1[1]; ?>"` it is run rightly. **That how to return member of $array1 with actual index if my code is wrong?**

```
<?php $array1 = array("-74.0061,40.712", "40.712,40.712", "19.291,50.712"); ?>

<script>
    for (i = 0; i != "<?php echo count($array1); ?>"; i++) {
                                        //there
        var from_array = "<?php echo $array1["+i+"]; ?>";   
        document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = from_array;   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you can't mix php (server-side code) and javascript (client-side code) like that. for example $array1 is defined in PHP code, but you try to access it and index in a JS loop. Surely this won't never work ; either do all code in PHP or all in JS ; also, I submitted an edit to remove nonsense tags (string, int)

Comment: `Undefined index: +i+` is what you should be seeing in HTML source.

Comment: @Pierre When making (suggestive) edits, please make sure to add relevant tag(s) if they're missing from what's posted. I had to improve your edit and to add the missing "javascript" tag. *Merci!*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Indeed, sorry I missed that !

Comment: No worries @Pierre :) Just a bit of a side note.

Comment: No, this is rightly run code: https://textuploader.com/149de

Comment: @Pierre I can´t do all code in PHP or all code in javascript because  $array1 representant array acquired from phpmyadmin and these data I want give to javascript openlayers map code. I must combinate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate JS array on server side using php, and then operate with JS array on client side

```
<script>
    var arr = [
    <?php 
         $array1 = array("-74.0061,40.712", "40.712,40.712", "19.291,50.712"); 
         $str = '';
        foreach($array1 as $val) {
            $str .= ("'".$val . "',");
        }
        echo $str;
    ?>
    ];
    for (i = 0; i !=  arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't read js values from php or php values from js. The code from  link (https://textuploader.com/149de), that loop doesn't iterate through loop. It uses `1` as the index.

```
var from_array = "<?php echo $array1[1]; ?>";
                                     ^^
```

You can try following

```
<script>
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i != count($array1); ?>"; $i++) {  
        echo "document.getElementById(".$i.").innerHTML ='".$array1[$i]."';";
    }
?>
</script>
```